# How to set up a cron job to run an executable every hour?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cron

I need to set up a cron job that runs an executable compiled using gcc once every hour.

I logged in as root and typed `crontab -e`

Then I entered the following and saved the file.

```
0 * * * *  /path_to_executable
```

However, the cron job does not work.

I see that when I type `/...path_to_executable` I get a segmentation fault.
I can only execute the executable from the folder it is located in.
Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Comment: That's a bad title.  You know how to set up the cron job; what you want to know is how to make the command work.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com (not directly related to programming)

Comment: Wrong title, but this is how i found the solution.

Comment: Your executable is probably started. I recommend using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) inside it (and at least make a log message at start, to be sure it is started).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
0 * * * * cd folder_containing_exe && ./exe_name
```

should work unless there is something else that needs to be setup for the program to run.

Comment: use && instead of ;, otherwise interessting stuff may happen (especially when used with rm)

Comment: You're right. && is much better if there is a chance the cd target doesn't exist (for example if the diretory is on an NFS server that happens to be down).

Comment: Note that you also need an absolute path (ie from the root directory) afaik

Answer (score 8):

The solution to solve this is to find out why you're getting the segmentation fault, and fix that.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `@hourly` instant of `0 * * * *`

Comment: curious with this solution what minute does it run at does @hourly imply at 0?

Comment: @ojblass `@hourly` is an exact synonym of `0 * * * *`, there is no difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Ubuntu, you can put a shell script in one of these directories: `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.monthly` or `/etc/cron.weekly`.

For more detail, check out this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean the executable fails to run , if invoked from any other directory?  This is rather a bug on the executable. One potential reason could be the executable  requires some shared libraires from the installed folder.  You may check  environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
path_to_exe >> log_file
```

to see the output of your command
also errors can be redirected with

```
path_to_exe &> log_file
```

also you can use

`crontab -l`

to check if your edits were saved.

Comment: crontab -l shows the cron job when I login as root.
I tried the log_file but it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not run the **`C` executable** that way, I wrote a simple `shell script` that does the following

```
cd /..path_to_shell_script
./c_executable_name
```

In the cron jobs list, I call the shell script.