# Cron to fire a compiled gfortran file

Tags: fortran, cron, gfortran

I am attempting to use cron to fire a compiled fortran file: a.out

When fired successfully, the a.out file will generate a fort.11 file.

I can successfully fire a.out manually, so gfortran is confirmed installed and working correctly.

Yet when attempting to fire a.out using a cron scheduled task - all that is generated is an empty cron.log file.

At least I can see that the scheduled task is firing, but I cannot get the compiled fortran file to run.

I am using a mac.

My crontab script:

```
42 13 * * * /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/WeatherForecaster/_fortran/hour36/a.out >> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/Weather-Forecaster/_fortran/hour36/cron.log
```

So my question is: what may I be doing wrong that is causing my cron job to not generate output?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling your program as a shell script in your crontab.  Your crontab should be:

```
31 10 * * * /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/Weather-Forecaster/_fortran/hour36/a.out
```

Also note that you only need gfortran installed and working to produce the executable, once you have an executable, running no longer depends on the compiler, but may depend on a shared libraries.  Thus the ability to run an executable doesn't really confirm that gfortran is installed properly, it was the compiling of the program that verified that.

Comment: Thanks for trying Casey and the further explanation.  I removed /bin/sh and I still do not get any output.  I have updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I found my answer:

[How to set up a cron job to run an executable every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474280/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-an-executable-every-hour)

What my successful cron task looks like:

```
31 14 * * * cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/Weather-Forecaster/_fortran/hour36/ && ./a.out
```