# Crontab suddenly stop working on server?

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have some crontab set on server on linux platform.Before that 2 days all the cron was running.I dont know what happen with crontab that they are not working now.

All the cron was running before and  i have added a new crontab after that they are not running may be this is the problem or is there other problem with that.

I have check ther permission but that is ok with.

New cron i have add look like that:

```
*/15 * * * * php myproject/sendmail.php
30 5 * * * php myproject/sendmailOnDiscount.php
* */1 * * * php myproject/sendInvitaion.php
```

The last one have added and before that other was running well.
After adding crontab sendInvitation.php crontab has stop working.

Could any one tell me why crontab is not working now.(All the crontab has stop working)

Comment: Well, given that `php myproject/sendInvitaion.php` appears to have a typo, check for that first.

Comment: sendInvitation.php is meant to be run at every hour. Have you tried using '0 * * * * php myproject/sendInvitation.php' as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474280/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-an-executable-every-hour

Comment: @SINGHKD Is your script is running manually?

Comment: yes @Miya G its running manually...Thanks

Comment: @arshan Thanks, But why all the crontab stop runnning even all the cron run on manually.

Comment: @SINGHKD may be because the php scripts are ok but there is some syntax issue in crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is off, you can turn it on with this command

```
service crond start
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i have checked  pgrep cron its giving a pid.But before that all crontab was running

Comment: you can check cron log `tail -fn 100 /var/log/cron`

Comment: there is no cron folder of file inside log...where else i could check for log..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this problem occurs due to script file permission and ownership of script files. The same problem was faced by me. I found that my script owner was not a super user e.g. root.

So, you have to set the permission and ownership of your scrip as super user. Find below.

First of all edit your crontab as super user.(in RHEL like below)

```
[abc@host] crontab -e
```

and save crontab :wq!

Now set permission for script

```
[abc@host] chmod +x script.sh
[abc@host] chown root:root script.sh
```

Now restart your crontab.(in RHEL like below)

```
[abc@host] /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Comment: But why it have stop all other cron who were running before it.

Comment: When you do edit in your crontab it reflect ownership or script e.g. if you are going to edit crontab with another user except root. Crontab run on root level user.