# Crontab stopped working suddenly, no errors

Tags: linux, cron, raspbian

I have had two scripts running via crontab for a while now. Suddenly, it stopped working. This is on a RaspberryPi, and this is all it does, so I haven't installed new software, etc. (The only thing that updates is the `sudo apt-get update` and `... upgrade` commands.

Here's my only crontab command:

```
...
# m h  dom mon dow   command
31 14 * * * python /mnt/ExternalDrive/FolderA/my_file.py
```

Nothing seems to happen. I don't believe the file runs.  At 14:31, I ran `pgrep -l python` to see if python was running, and it doesn't return anything.

In `my_file.py` I have tried both shebangs, `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

When I do `which python`, I get: `/usr/bin/python`.

I have looked all over, and restarted crontab, etc. but it doesn't work.  I've also [set the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493042/crontab-suddenly-stop-working-on-server) on the file, and [installed postfix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog) to no avail.

Running `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and I see `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`, but am not sure if that affects this.

I even deleted the crontab file, restarted the computer/Pi, and re-created one (`sudo crontab -e`).

Again, this was working fine before, but suddenly doesn't.  Running the script from the terminal works fine (`python /mnt/.../my_file.py`)

Comment: That syslog error ("No MTA installed, discarding output") sounds like the script is producing errors, but that crond doesn't have a way to report them, so it's just discarding. I'd try adding something like `>/tmp/my_file.log 2>&1` to the cron entry, and see if you get an indication of the problem in that log file.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - That's odd, because when I run the script from the terminal, there are no errors at all.  But I'll try that and update OP.

Comment: @BruceWayne cron jobs run in a significantly different environment from your regular terminal, so it's not at all surprising that something will work in one but fail in the other.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Yep, you're right. The log is telling me that a python module isn't installed...but it is? Again, it runs via terminal just fine. What happened to where cron suddenly is throwing this issue?

Comment: Install email with `apt-get install postfix`, so you can see the error messages.

Comment: @Philippe - Still get that error, should have mentioned in OP, sorry.

Comment: The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is probably not set for the cron job, so it doesn't know where to look for modules. cron jobs don't run the shell init scripts (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc) that're normally used to set up your environment, so anything set up there will normally be missing in cron jobs. As for why it stopped working: I have no idea. To find out, you'll need to troubleshoot to understand the current problem, *then* try to figure out why that problem didn't used to exist.

Comment: I put `* * * * * some thing` in the root's crontab. I had `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`. After I installed postfix, I have `raspberrypi CRON[23829]: (root) CMD (some thing)`, and I received email `/bin/sh: 1: some: not found`