# How can i run cron-job every 1 hour in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cron, cron-task

I want to run a cron for every 1 hour.

What i tried :

1. **0 */1 * * *  /home/username/test.sh**
2. **0 * * * * /home/username/test.sh**

But, i am not sure, which one is right ?
Can you please help me to decide . which one i should use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a cron job to run an executable every hour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474280/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-an-executable-every-hour)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to set cronjob on ubuntu for every 1 hour
0 * * * * or you can put it in cron.hourly directory 
For more details you can refer link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: You write every 1 minute.

Comment: The above command is correct @SanyaSnex . The above command will execute every hour like 01:00, 02:00 and so on. If you want to change minutes than you can change 0 with any minute between 0-59.

Answer (score -2):

```
    # Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
    # +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
    # |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
    # |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
    # |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
    # |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
    # |  |  |  |  |
    # *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * */1 * * *  root /bin/sh /home/username/test.sh
```

Comment: If you know that there are _hundreds_ of dupe targets, why do answer the question instead of flagging it as being duplicate??